# Databinding in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am binding a datagrid with a table. There is one datagrid column as--

```
     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title">
```

The 'Title' field in the table returns the value--
"http://bhu453526d:1234/Item/results.aspx?searchId=, test 123"
but i want to bind only the value "test 123".

Please suggest how to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to crop the string before binding it to the datagrid. But how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably how I would do it. Instead of a `BoundColumn`, use a `TemplateColumn`:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Title">
    <ItemTemplate><%#GetID(Eval("Title"))%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

And in your code-behind page:

```
protected static string GetID(object Title)
{
    string[] queryString = Title.ToString().Split('?');

    // Only if you're sure you want the value of the first element in the QueryString
    return queryString[1].Split('=')[1];
}
```